# React Native test Error: Redux-persist: config.storage is required

Tags: typescript, react-native, jestjs, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

I setup redux-persist in my app. And it works great. My problem its when I try to run my single default unit test. I get the error:

FAIL  **tests**/App-test.tsx
● Test suite failed to run

```
redux-persist: config.storage is required. Try using one of the provided storage engines `import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'`

  10 | };
  11 |
> 12 | const loginReducer = persistCombineReducers(persistConfig, {
     |                      ^
  13 |   login: LoginReducer,
  14 | });
  15 |

  at persistReducer (node_modules/redux-persist/lib/persistReducer.js:39:32)
  at persistCombineReducers (node_modules/redux-persist/lib/persistCombineReducers.js:17:10)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/redux/store/store.ts:12:22)
  at Object.<anonymous> (App.tsx:6:1)
```

My store its like this:

```
import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import {LoginReducer} from '../reducers/Reducers';
import {persistCombineReducers} from 'redux-persist';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'login',
  version: 1,
  storage: AsyncStorage,
};

const loginReducer = persistCombineReducers(persistConfig, {
  login: LoginReducer,
});

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    login: loginReducer,
  },
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({serializableCheck: false}),
});
```

Versions:

```
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.10",
"redux-persist": "^6.0.0"
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.5",
"react": "18.1.0",
"react-native": "0.70.1",
"react-redux": "^8.0.4",
"jest": "25.x.x",
```

This is driving me crazy

Comment: I didn't find the `persistCombineReducers` API from `redux-persist` documentation